# How to display an image dynamically from database on the jsp page

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2

i am using Struts and hibernate with oracle database and trying to store the image in the database and retrieve the image from database and display it on the jsp page 
i am able to set and get the image but able to display the image on jsp page...

using this code...

```
public String getImage() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String simage=new String(image, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(simage);
    try {
        FileOutputStream fw = new FileOutputStream("ItemImages/"+simage);
        fw.write(image);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
//Logger.getLogger(Items.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } finally
    {
        return simage;
    }

}

public void setImage(String image) {    
    byte [] bimage = image.getBytes();
    this.image = bimage;
}
```

jsp code:-

```
<ss:iterator value="#productList.products" var="item">
<img src="ItemImages/<ss:property value="#item.image" />"></img>
</ss:iterator>
```

i have created an folder `ItemImages` in web pages but i am not able to access it please help me..

Comment: You say "I am able to set and get the image but able to display the image on jsp page.".  

Do you perhaps mean "I am able to set and get the image but am unable to display the image on jsp page."

Comment: yaa i am unable to display it on the jsp page

Comment: see `html` generated code what it's showing with `img` tag.

Comment: it is not showing anything

Comment: I think `getImage()` returns the `image` not the `url`. `src` Specifies the `URL` of an `image`.

Comment: when i am uploading image using <s:file name="image" lable="Uoload image" /> tag on jsp page, it is returning me only name of the image in string form how  can i get complete image

Comment: <s:file name="image" label="Upload Image" />

Comment: From what class is the java code from? What do the action definitions look like? What is the code of the `ItemImages` action?

Answer (score -1):

my suggestion is store your image path in database which is same as physical path of image.after that make list of image path and pass it to jsp and iterate it.

Comment: then how would i store the image on a particular path

Comment: i am taking the image from the jsp page only

Comment: suppose your physical path of image is c:\abc then strore image path in db as c:\abc\1.jpg.